# Typescript does not recognize callback's param type

Tags: typescript

I have the following function and its callback type:

```
type Callbacks = {
    onSuccess: (a: string) => void;
};

function t(event: string, ...args: [...any, Callbacks]) {

}
```

It works as expected but one thing, `onSuccess` function has a string param but TS can't recognize it and says that it has any type but I explicitly set it to string.

```
t("eventName", "bobo", 123, {onSuccess: (asd) => {
    // "asd" is a string but TS says that it's an any
    // Parameter 'asd' implicitly has an 'any' type
}})
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYGcoF4oDeAUFKVAPYB2AygK5poRZYBcUAFHG1sAE4CWlAOYBKPAD4oAN3L8AJgG4iAXyVEAZrUppg-KlGDsIUiJWDc+goQBooAOgdxeQ1lADaDu3Eohb8JKiYWAC6YsQqRJGGAEQAFhBI5NG20cjkaclQAIwATADMtgRUdAxMrpxYcmK4ksRkUAD0DVDRcJXRUPw4cFA8AsJQyLTAUAAq1L1wIDjAsXAj-MAA5N2UUN4gKsoiQA)

What should I change in order to let TS recognize the callback's params type because manually specifying them every time is tedious?

P.S. it's a simplified example of my problem

Comment: I would maybe report this, it looks like a bug to me.  TS knows it's a string too, as if you change `asd:number` it will error.  I would post an issue here, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues just double check a similar issue doesn't exist first.  Handling implicit types in Typescript, is just as important as checking Types, otherwise we get Type Code bloat,  (not good)..

Comment: This is a current limitation with contextual typing of function parameters with leading/middle rest elements; it is reported at [ms/TS#45972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45972).  Until and unless this is changed, the workaround I'd use is to make `t` generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NV4XGW).  Does this fully address your question?  If so I can write up an answer explaining and elaborating.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz hello, I've checked the playground and it fully addresses my question, thanks! Feel free to write up an answer and I'll approve it :)

Comment: As a workaround more appropriate to what the author was looking for, I removed my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is currently a missing feature in TypeScript.  A function whose parameter list has [leading or middle rest elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#leadingmiddle-rest-elements-in-tuple-types) does not seem to benefit from [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) of its input parameters when called. There is a request at [microsoft/TypeScript#45972](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45972) to change this.  It's (as of 2022-07-06) marked as "awaiting more feedback", so if you want to see this changed it wouldn't hurt to give it a  and comment with your use case if you think it's compelling.  It wouldn't necessarily *help*, but I wouldn't hurt.

In the meantime, if you want to work around it, you could make `t()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function in a type parameter corresponding to the leading rest tuple.  (The original pull request for leading/middle rest elements at [microsoft/TypeScript#41544](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41544) mentions that generic types are better supported.)

That would look like

```
function t<T extends any[]>(event: string, ...args: [...T, Callbacks]) {}
```

And then it works as desired:

```
t("hello", "bobo", 123, {
    onSuccess: (asd) => asd.toUpperCase() // asd is seen as string
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgGwQIzgYwNYGcoF4oDeAUFKVAPYB2AygK5poRZYBcUAFHG1sAE4CWlAOYBKPAD4oAN3L8AJgG4iAXyVEAZrUppg-KlGAAeACpQIAD2ARKcnHEogA2gF1x7CFOvBufQUIA0UAB0IXC8QqxQjiFBxoHwSKiYWM5ixMpEmcDsAEQAFhBI5DmBOcjk5SVQAIwATADMgcRkFDT0jMxsnFhyYriScD1BwOQAqmCQvPBYEOxiAPTzUINyUPw4M9bLG77CKiJAA)